# Did Barry Allen and Felicity Smoak have a past relationship?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In Part 2 of *Elseworlds*, when Felicity finds out that Barry and Oliver have switched bodies, she says "it's not every day you find out your husband is your ex and vice-versa."  This implies that Barry Allen is her "ex."  But... when did that happen?

The only thing I can recall that even comes close is the brief moment in one of the early crossover episodes (can't remember which off the top of my head) when the two both acknowledge that they'd make a great couple, but that they can't because (in essence) she's a main character on a different show and she can't leave it to be with him on his show.

In other words, as far as I'm aware at least, he's someone where they both decided not to have a relationship in the first place.  So what did Felicity mean with this line?

Comment: Weren't they in a long-distance relationship of sorts on *Arrow,* prior to the commencement of *the Flash?*  I know Barry made a couple of appearances there before he got his own show.

Comment: @Steve-O Nope.  Barry showed up one time on *Arrow*, where his character was introduced.  At the end of that story, he returned home in a big hurry, wanting to get there in time for the particle accelerator activation, and ended up in a coma in the aftermath of the events of that night.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - However, Felicity and Barry were clearly attracted to each other during that one *Arrow* episode. And it was at least implied that Felicity regularly made the trip to visit the comatose Barry, as I recall.

Comment: @RDFozz yea but that doesn't mean they were in a relationship, seeing as Barry was in a coma for those visit. also jsut because you are attracted to each other doesn't mean you are dating, so they were never even together for them to breakup to become ex's.

Comment: Felicity's view and Barry's could be different; as noted, she spent a fair amount of time with him while he was in a coma. She might feel like he was an "ex", to her.

Answer (score 1):

When Barry and Felicity met they seemed to have an instant connection. And Barry was interested in in her, but she was also kind of interested in Oliver.

After the particle accelerator  accident, Felicity is said to have visited Barry in the hospital until he was moved to Star Labs.

This somewhat campy video shows all the Barry and Felicity scenes leading up on their kiss.

So they kind of entertained a mutual attraction / flirty relationship for a little bit. This was before Felicity eventually hooked up with Oliver. I personally wouldn't go so far as to call Barry her "ex" but clearly that is how she thinks of it.